# 'You in my office' AAVE meaning

Tags: expressions

I'm watching Glory Road (2006) and there's a moment where one of the players yells to another "you in my office!" after pushing him to the side to dunk. What's the meaning of this expression? I'm guessing it's AAVE because I know in AAVE the verb to be tends to be omitted.

Comment: [Get away, as you are] in my personal space?

Comment: What do *you* mean by "pushing him to the side to dunk"?

Comment: From @YosefBaskin does the player yell "You in my face!" ?

Comment: I was watching with English subs and it said "you in my office!"
And I don't have enough basketball vocabulary, sorry, but I mean, the two players are near the basket, one jumps, the other tries to block him, then the first one pushes him and... scores

Comment: Subtitles are frequently incorrect.

Comment: Even official ones? I was watching on Disney+

Comment: It probably means "you are in my office". The speaker might be using as a jokey way of telling the person to get out of their way, with the meaning to "you are in my space" or "you are in the place where I do my work" (that work being scoring points). "My office" might refer to a personal space of some sort, either something a parent might say about a home office, or something a boss might say. But this is just a guess.

Comment: I haven't seen it, but  "You!  In my office!" is what an angry school principal might say to a student who has committed some offense. It means, "Go to my office".  It is not AAVE on its surface.  It could be said by the principal at an all-white school.   It might be related to the expression "He schooled me" meaning "He taught me a lesson, namely, that he was the superior athlete".  I suspect it is some such assertion of dominance.

Comment: I found a Youtube version. The player says to the defender, whom he has knocked to the floor: "You're in *my* office, chump".   Meaning, "I'm the boss here".

Comment: I see, thank you for being so helpful everybody!